# Angular 7: CustomMaterialModule is not working in FeatureLazyLoadedModule

Tags: angular

I have created CustomMaterialModule and imported in AppModule as well as I have created FeatureLazymodule, here I have lazy-loaded some components but material controls are not working and giving me this Error, If I add CustomMaterialModule also in FeatureLazymodule  so it works fine, My Question why I have to import CustomMaterialModule in FeatureLazymodule although I have already imported in Main AppModule?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGntY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Doesn't matter**.

Long answer: lately the Angular team explained it in their [FAQ](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice)s:

> **What if I import the same module twice?**
>
> That's not a problem. When three modules all import Module 'A',
> Angular evaluates Module 'A' once, the first time it encounters it,
> and doesn't do so again.
>
> That's true at whatever level A appears in a hierarchy of imported
> NgModules. When Module 'B' imports Module 'A', Module 'C' imports 'B',
> and Module 'D' imports [C, B, A], then 'D' triggers the evaluation of
> 'C', which triggers the evaluation of 'B', which evaluates 'A'. When
> Angular gets to the 'B' and 'A' in 'D', they're already cached and
> ready to go.
>
> Angular doesn't like NgModules with circular references, so don't let
> Module 'A' import Module 'B', which imports Module 'A'.

notice however, that this is NOT to say [providing services](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-is-it-bad-if-a-shared-module-provides-a-service-to-a-lazy-loaded-module) works the same.